# Differences between two .bashrc commands

Tags: bash, export

I have this line of code :

```
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"
```

Is there a difference between

- `eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"`

and more simply

- `SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe` (or `export SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe`)

(What is the difference between using `export` and not using it by the way?)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe` isn't `SHELL` being set to `/bin/sh lesspipe`; it's running `lesspipe` with the environment variable `SHELL` set to `/bin/sh` for that command only. If that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference.

The second example just runs `lesspipe` with the `SHELL` variable set to `/bin/sh` in its environment.

The first example does the same, but takes the output and runs that as a command in your current shell.